# Javascript Scrolltop for fixed menu position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I want to stick my menu bar after scrolling few pixels in javascript but it is not working as it should. Here is my script.
**JavaScript Code:**

```
window.onscroll = function() {stick()};

function stick() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 150) {
        document.getElementById("test").style.position = "fixed";
        document.getElementById("test").style.background = "blue";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("test").style.position = "initial";
    }
}
```

**Problem:**
Whenever I scroll even one pixel my test id get fixed. I tried to change scrollTop value in if but nothing effective. Any attention will be appreciated.

**Update:**
Here is also error using ids.

```
<script>
document.getElementById("cntnr").onscroll = function() {stick()};

function stick() {
    if (document.getElementById("cntnr").scrollTop > 119) {
    document.getElementById("navdwn").style.position = "fixed";
    } else {
    document.getElementById("navdwn").style.position = "initial";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try with (position ) absolute instead of fixed ?

Comment: @MalithMcR his if condition is wrong, When he scrolls down always code in if condition will be executed,

Comment: create JSfiddle for your code

Comment: Post your html code also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verify your `If` condition, to fix the menu current document scrolled to 150px top

change:

```
window.onscroll = function() {stick()};

function stick() {
if (document.body.scrollTop > 150 ) {
    document.getElementById("test").style.position = "fixed";
    document.getElementById("test").style.background = "blue";
} else {
    document.getElementById("test").style.position = "initial";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code, you need the parseInt() function of the javascript to make the 
`document.documentElement.scrollTop` equal to integer

```
window.onscroll = function() {stick()};

var offset = document.documentElement.scrollTop

function stick() {
    if (parseInt(offset) > 150) {
       document.getElementById("test").style.position = "fixed";
       document.getElementById("test").style.background = "blue";
    } else {
       document.getElementById("test").style.position = "initial";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `document.body.scrollTop` will be greater than `0` as soon as you start scrolling. The **OR** operator **will not check for the second condition if the first condition is true**.

Hence as soon as you start scrolling the first condition becomes true and then the test id gets fixed.

Change the condition to `if (document.body.scrollTop > 150 ) {....` and it will work.